# laravel submit data return no error message

Tags: php, laravel

I keep getting this different kind of no error message nowadays and I have no idea how to solve them. In the past, at least it gave me some hint but now, it doesn't. Can anyone help me with this problem? This happen when I try to save my data, in the past it was working fine, I didn't do any update on laravel at all and have no idea what does this error do. I google and see many people say it is the fault of the GET where it should be POST but I am using POST. Thanks for helping in advance, could you guys give me some link for me to understand how to solve a no error message as well.

AddVerification.blade.php

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('/AddInfo')}}">

                  {{ method_field('PUT')  }}
                  {{ csrf_field() }}
```

....
...

VerificationController:

```
public function VerificationSubmit(Request $request){
     $verification = new Verification;
        $PersonalInfo = new PersonalInfo;
        $verification->name = $request->input('name');
        ...
        $id = $request->user_id;
        $id= PersonalInfo::find($id);
        $id->verifications()->save($verification);


    return redirect('/summary');
}
```

routes: (route used to submit result)

```
Route::post('/AddInfo','VerificationController@VerificationSubmit');
```

No error message:

[image]

Comment: you would need to show the relevant routes, this means you are trying to hit a route with a http method it doesn't support

Comment: you're using `PUT` method not `POST` method.

Comment: I tried using POST as well, but doesn't work @Webinion

Comment: I added the route that I used to submit the data @lagbox

Comment: In the past this whole things works but suddenly i can't submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your route defined as a `POST` route yet you are spoofing a `PUT` method on the form. That makes it not match.

You need to remove the method field or make the route a `PUT` route instead.

Comment: I have done that before and it doesn't work, in the past I used this method and it is able to submit

Comment: what.. Damn, but I tried removing it as well and changing it and nothing happen still same error

Comment: Just to confirm, change into this right? {{ method_field('POST')  }} if not remove it, right?

Comment: remove that or adjust the route definition, one or the other

Comment: The removing part and replacing part of the method_field('PUT') doesn't work, but if i do this to the route, Route::put('/AddInfo','VerificationController@VerificationSubmit');, and change method to put in the form it work I think

Comment: that is what i said ... either adjust the route definition **OR** remove the method field

Comment: oh hahaha sorry I didn't see it properly thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `{{ method_field('PUT') }}` from the form then. It makes the form submit a PUT request, whereas in the routes you have defined a POST route.